# Is there a term for mixing deferred and eager evaluation?

Tags: terminology, evaluation-strategies

I've written a model which utilises deferred evaluation for many aspects of its feature but in one instance of its use it is mixed with threaded eager evaluation for things that are expected to be used at some point.

Is there a term for mixing lazy and eager evaluation, possibly when mixing with threading?